# 32pt text adds unwanted padding

Tags: css, text, padding

When I add the 36px "Announcement" text to the `<div>` below, it adds a ton of padding around just the text that is 36px and I cannot get rid of it. I did some research and tried changing the padding of the `<div>` and the `<body>` in my stylesheet, but that did not get rid of the padding. Can somebody please explain how to remove the excess padding that is around just the 36px text?

```
<div style="float:right; width:697px; height:90px; position:relative; top:-50px;">
<p style="text-align:center; font-size:36px;">Announcements</p>
<br/>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam eget.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you mean the "Announcements" paragraph?  The default style of a `p` element normally includes a margin, so try `margin: 0` on your `p`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to explicitely set the `line-height` CSS attribute, also make sure you set `margin` to 0.

Comment: Changing both of these attributes fixed it. Thank you.